# Why can't I play Simpsons: Tapped Out while signed into Origin?

Tags: origin, simpsons-tapped-out

I keep trying to sign into my Origin account while playing Tapped Out, but I keep having the same problem.

If I play without the Origin login, everything works amazingly.

If I sign into my Origin account, I just get server error after server error, and it just refuses to connect to the server at all, which means I can't play.

There aren't any specific errors given, just an image of Bart Simpson holding a power cord, and the following text: "Sorry, an error occurred and we can't connect to the server. Please try again." And then an option to retry connecting, which results in the same error image.

I have tried both over a 3G connection, and wifi, and either way, it refuses to connect to the server if I have signed into Origin.

Is there some way to fix this so I can sign into Origin AND play?

Comment: Could you give us some more information? What are the errors Origin is giving you?

Comment: Because Origin.

Comment: @kalina I tried, but the game doesn't really tell you a whole heck of a lot, which is part of my frustration, because without any sort of feedback from the game, I don't know where to start trying to fix it!

Comment: I think this is a mobile game, yes? Are you playing it over a 3G connection or wifi? I've noticed sometimes origin login for apps doesn't play well with mobile networks for me.

Comment: @TZHX added that information. :)

Comment: Have you tried logging into Origin from outside the game?  Could it be that their servers are down?

Comment: @DavidM Origin sign in works anywhere else (including on the same game on my sister's phone). It just doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Oh well.  It's just broked I guess . . .

Comment: I know that you have to download a large amount of data, but try to delete the entire game and install it again.

Comment: @aman207 the reason I haven't tried that is because I am concerned that since I am playing anonymously (because Origin does not work), I will lose any progress I have.

Comment: Oh you haven't previously played with an account. Ok I see. The same thing happened to me a long while ago when origin wasn't required. You might just have to wait a day or so and try again.

Comment: @aman207 This isn't a one time thing - I have tried multiple times on multiple days, and I always have the same problem.

Comment: Well then I'm afraid it doesn't look good. You can try to contact EA.

Comment: maybe origin and Simpsons tapped out use to much data together to use out of wifi, like not being able to download games over a certain amount of space.

Comment: @bobatbobdotbob I use wifi, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to saves.

Origin makes a server side copy of your save when you are signed in, that's why when you sign in on other devices you can continue from where you left off.

The save on Origins server side can be corrupted in which you will need to contact them to remove the save on the server.

So when your're getting an error its actually trying to load a corrupted save from the Origin server.

You will have to unfortunately have to star again though when you use Origin if you contact them to remove the save